# PhantomJS not returning results

Tags: phantomjs

I'm testing out PhantomJS and trying to return all startups listed on angel.co. I decided to go with PhantomJS since I would need to paginate through the front page by clicking "Next" at the bottom. Right now this code does not return any results. I'm completely new to PhantomJS and have read through all the code examples so any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://angel.co/startups', function(status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
     page.evaluate(function() {
        var list = document.querySelectorAll('div.resume');
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
           console.log((i + 1) + ":" + list[i].innerText);
        }
     });
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, console messages evaluated on the **page** will not appear in your PhantomJS console.

When you execute code under `page.evaluate(...)`, that code is being executed in the context of the page. So when you have `console.log((i + 1) + ":" + list[i].innerText);`, that is being logged in the headless browser itself, rather than in PhantomJS.

If you want all console messages to be passed along to PhantomJS itself, use the following after opening your page:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };
```

`page.onConsoleMessage` is triggered whenever you print to the console from within the page. With this callback, you're asking PhantomJS to echo the message to its own standard output stream.

For reference, your final code would look like (this prints successfully for me):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://angel.co/startups', function(status) {
    page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
         page.evaluate(function() {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('div.resume');
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
               console.log((i + 1) + ":" + list[i].innerText);
            }
         });
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: bonus kudos points if you can show how to do this with CasperJS.. I can access casper.page but there is no onConsoleMessage option.

Comment: never mind.. worked it out: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html